# Slight generalization of differentiation so that Re{z} is differentiable in the complex plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

If I make a small change $\delta z$ to a complex number $z$, then $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{e}\{z\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\mathrm{e} \{z+\delta z\} = \mathbb{R}\mathrm{e} \{z\}+\mathbb{R}\mathrm{e} \{\delta z\}$. Differentiation is closely related to finding linear approximations to functions about points. There is no constant $\alpha$ so that $\alpha \delta z=\mathbb{R}\mathrm{e}\{\delta z\}$, so conventionally we would say that no derivative could exist.

However, if I map $z$ to the real-valued vector $\hat z=[\mathrm{Re}\{z\},\mathrm{Im}\{z\}]^T$, then the real-part function becomes the projecting matrix $R=\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$. Clearly, the derivative with respect to $\hat z$ of $R\hat z$ is $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$. This implies that there is something nearby to complex numbers where the derivative of $\mathrm{Re}\{ z\}$ is defined. What am I dealing with here?

Comment: The function $(x,y) \mapsto x$ is differentiable, the function $z \mapsto \operatorname{re} z$ is not. Differentiability with respect to a complex scalar imposes more constraints that differentiability with respect to two real variables. Analytic functions are open maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\phi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb C:(x,y)\mapsto x+iy$ and its inverse $\phi^{-1}:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R^2:z\mapsto(\mathop{\mathrm{Re}}z,\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}z)$.

If $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is holomorphic, then $\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ\phi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ is differentiable and its differential at any point is of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$, but the converse is not true. The function $f=\mathop{\mathrm{Re}}$ provides an example.

Comment: Just a note, the form of the differential makes it look like it belongs in $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$.